# Tomcat 8.5 resolves same variable differently

Tags: java, jsp, variables, tomcat

When expanding a HTML page with embedded variables from JSP code my code produced inexplicable results. The variable "String completename" expands at first to

http://www.formatika.de/cococo.de/products/Sources/Isabelle/Doc/Tutorial/document/Isa-logics.pdf

and 2 lines later to

http://localhost:8080/cococo.de/products/Sources/Isabelle/Doc/Tutorial/document/Isa-logics.pdf

in the following code fragment:

```
<div>
  <table border="0" align="center" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr  align="center"><td align="center">
        <div>
            <a href="<%=completename %>" title="<%=showname%>" target="_blank"><%=filename%><br><br>
              <iframe src='<%=completename %>' width='<%=width%>' height='<%=height%>' type='application/pdf'>
              </iframe>
            </a>
        </div>
      </td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

it can be observed in this URL

http://formatika.de/print.jsp?content=source&file=products/Sources/Isabelle/Doc/Tutorial/document/Isa-logics.pdf

Does anyone know where to search? I use Apache Tomcat 8.0.27 with JAVA EE 6 Web.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer/bug; it was because the Tomcat still is hidden behind the IIS and therefore the name was here resolved to "localhost:8080" instead of the hostname at IIS.